# Agent Pool cannot be found after creation

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to run a localised build on a particular agent pool.

The idea is that I run a pipeline in two stages.

First stage runs an Ansible playbook that creates an agent pool in Azure DevOps, provisions a VM in an Azure Virtual Network, installs an agent, registers the agent on this newly created pool, and authorises all pipelines to use the pool. This is because there is a requirement to run Ansible playbooks on different Virtual networks and VSTS needs to connect to the the correct agents.

Second stage uses the newly created pool to find an agent and run another Ansible Playbook in the actual desired virtual network.

The problem is that the second stage fails with this error:

"The pipeline is not valid. Could not find a pool with ID 0. The pool does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."

This is basically what I'm doing:

Stage 1:

```
  displayName: Environment Preparation
  jobs:
  - job: Prepare_Customer_Environment
    displayName: Prepare Target Environment
    variables:
    - group: Azure-Ansible-Variables
    pool:
     name: 'Infrastructure-Agents'
    workspace:
     clean: all 
    steps:
    - task: Ansible@0
      displayName: Prepare Target Environment for Deployment
      inputs: 
       SUBSCRIPTION_ID: $(SUBSCRIPTION-ID)
       failOnStderr: false
       playbookPathOnAgentMachine: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ansible/playbooks/environment.yml'
```

Stage 2:

```
- stage: Environment_Provisioning
  displayName: Environment Provisioning
  jobs:
  - job: Update_Customer_Environment
    displayName: Update Target Environment
    variables:
    - group: Azure-Ansible-Variables
    pool:
     name: $(environment)-$(env_id)
    workspace:
     clean: all 
    steps:
```

The name of the pool is correct, I've checked it like 10 times already.

In Ansible, I create the Pool using REST API calls:

```
- name: VSTS Agent Specific Configuration | Create the Agent Pool
  register: create_pool_result
  uri:
   url: "https://company.visualstudio.com/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
   method: POST
   body_format: json
   body: {"name": "{{ hostvars['localhost']['resource_group'] }}","autoProvision": true}
   status_code: 
   - 200
   - 409
   headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer {{ hostvars['localhost']['current_bearer_token_3'] }}"
```

And I authorise its use here:

```
- name: VSTS Agent Specific Configuration | Authorise Agent Pool for all Pipelines
  register: authorise_pool_result
  uri:
   url: "https://dev.azure.com/Company/Project/_apis/build/authorizedresources?api-version=5.0-preview"
   method: PATCH
   body_format: json
   body: [{"name": "{{ hostvars['localhost']['resource_group'] }}","type": "queue","id": "{{ current_agent_pool_queue }}","authorized": true}]
   status_code: 
   - 200
   headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer {{ hostvars['localhost']['current_bearer_token_3'] }}"
```

All this works, but the second stage cannot find the pool.  I think this is because the yaml file gets loaded before the pool is created, and then it tries to find a resource that it thinks does not exist, I'm not sure.

Is there a way to reload the definition/build file? Or any way to get the service to find a resource that was created on-the-fly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you see the created Agent pool and the agents from the UI (I mean from Organization settings -> Agent pools) after the first stage? Can you use the agent pool in another separate pipeline? In addition, please also try giving a `depend on` setting for the second stage and check if that works.

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this?
I am currently try to archive basically the same and run into the same issue.
What I want to do is to use an agentless phase to create an agent pool which should be used by the following agent phase. The agent pool itself is created the right way because if I the pool is created **before** the build is queued everything works as expected.